# Is it possible in Ant to exclude one fileset from another?

Tags: ant

I tried many different things that looked like they could work, but nothing really did.
I just can't believe that something so simple and so useful is not implemented at all, so I thought, I'd ask before I give up.

Let's say I have several subsets of unit tests, because I want to run them in parallel:

```
<fileset id="foo.tests" dir="${test.build}">
   <include name="**/TestFoo*.class" />
</fileset>
<fileset id="bar.tests" dir="${test.build}">
   <include name="**/TestBar*.class" />
</fileset>
```

(IRL, these are long lists of actual test classes, not just a single pattern).

So, I want to create a third group of tests, that includes all test classes, that are not
included into one of those groups.
Effectively

```
<fileset id="other.tests" dir="${test.build}">
    <include name="**/Test*.class" />
    <exclude name="**/TestBar*.class" />
    <exclude name="**/TestFoo*.class" />
</fileset>
```

*Except*, like I said, these are not just single patterns, so, I am looking for away to avoid having to duplicate those long lists, and instead somehow exclude them by reference.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most straightforward way of doing this would be to create a `difference` resource collection, which will only select the files in your filesets that are not common among all of them. Here's some test code that demonstrates how to do this:

```
<target name="default">
    <delete dir="tmp" />
    <mkdir dir="tmp" />

    <touch file="tmp/Test1.class" />
    <touch file="tmp/Test3.class" />
    <touch file="tmp/Test2.class" />
    <touch file="tmp/TestFoo1.class" />
    <touch file="tmp/TestFoo3.class" />
    <touch file="tmp/TestFoo2.class" />
    <touch file="tmp/TestBar1.class" />
    <touch file="tmp/TestBar3.class" />
    <touch file="tmp/TestBar2.class" />

    <fileset dir="tmp" id="tests.all">
        <include name="Test*.class" />
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="tmp" id="tests.foo">
        <include name="TestFoo*.class" />
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="tmp" id="tests.bar">
        <include name="TestBar*.class" />
    </fileset>

    <difference id="tests.main">
        <fileset refid="tests.all" />
        <fileset refid="tests.foo" />
        <fileset refid="tests.bar" />
    </difference>

    <echo message="tests.main: ${toString:tests.main}" />
</target>
```

This way, a resource (fileset in this case) named `tests.main` will be created that contains all of the test classes that are not included in `tests.foo` or `tests.bar`.

Comment: Thanks, this does look like what I need ... but I'd like to understand what does this _do_ exactly? I mean, all three filesets are _different_ here ... so, how does it know to just subtract the other two from the first one, and not ... I dunno ... the other way around?

Comment: Also, this doesn't seem to be working for me: when I try to use `refid="tests.main"` in junit task, it tells me `tests.main does not denote a fileset" :(

Comment: The reason `difference` works here is because the fileset `tests.all` contains all of the test classes (including the Foo and Bar tests), while `tests.foo` and `tests.bar` only contain the Foo and Bar tests. In other words, `tests.foo` and `tests.bar` are subsets of `tests.all`, so the difference between them is just the stuff that those two don't contain.

Comment: Regarding the script failure, you will have to reference it as a `difference` type when performing operations on this resource collection, e.g. `<copy todir="tmp/subdir"><difference refid="tests.main" /></copy>`

Comment: Yes, but how does it know that I want the "difference" between the first one, and the union of the other two, and not, say between the second one and the union of first and third?

Comment: It's not doing anything based on order; just think of it as a XOR operation (rather than NAND)

Comment: Ah, XOR makes sense. So, if something is included in all three sets, it will still appear in the result then?

Comment: In that situation, Ant's `difference` operation is different from XOR (though I can't think of a situation in Ant where you'd actually want a true XOR). I don't think there's a boolean term that fits it exactly, but the logic is simply "after combining all sets, only keep the things that appear exactly once". You can see how Ant does it in the source code, which is pretty straightforward: https://github.com/apache/ant/blob/master/src/main/org/apache/tools/ant/types/resources/Difference.java